# how to put the selected data in modal window without using ajax?

Tags: php, html, sql

```
 <div class="modal-body">

            <p> list of order </p>
                <?php
                    $query20 = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM `order` natural join order_details natural join food where order_id = '$order_id' "); //query

                    while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query20)){

                        echo "<p>";
                        echo $list['food_name'];
                        echo '&nbsp'; 
                        echo $list['quantity']; 
                        echo "</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

is there any other way to retrieve data from sql then place it in the pop up window

Comment: Hmmm, using a supported database interface such as mysqli_ would be another way.

Comment: Do you use jquery ui?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?  Are you talking about using JavaScript to populate the order list after the document has loaded?